# Swift for Windows ./swiftc: Input/output error

Tags: swift, windows, bash, ubuntu

I just installed Swift on windows through ubuntu bash and now I'm trying to write my first program but I'm running into this error message when I try to compile. I followed this guide for installing. https://developerinsider.co/install-apple-swift-on-windows-10-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/

My program is just a single line

```
print("Hello world")
```

When I try to run the program I get the following error: syntax error near unexpected token '"Hello world"'

Anyone know how to fix this or is there a better way to run Swift on windows?

Comment: Try "$ swiftc yourProgramFile.swift" in the command line in the directory where you script file is.

Comment: I'm getting "$: command not found". I'm in the mnt/c/Swift directory using bash on ubuntu

Comment: Traditionally a shell prompt either ends with "$", "?" or "#". It's a technical shell sign. Don't enter it. Type only "swiftc yourFile.swift" in the command line.